# Uninterrupted listening to incoming sms messages in background - Service?

Tags: android

My application listens to incoming sms messages through SmsReceiver (which extends BroadcastReceiver).
SmsReceiver is registered in onStartCommand method of Service (to enable long-running listening for sms messages). onStartCommand returns Service.START_STICKY (to restart Service in case it's killed due to low memory conditions - if I understand docs correctly ;)).

Application uses several Activities (one of them starts Service by calling Context.startService).

The problem:
After all activities are gone, service continues to run **for some time** (at most several hours), and stops eventually.

How to maximize service running time in such conditions? Alternatively, what tricks would allow such functionality (uninterrupted listening to incoming sms messages without visible Activities, "background" task running indefinitely).

Answer (score 0):

Services are not meant to be persistent. Try polling at regular intervals.

http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/